# Как уничтожить сессионные переменные

Tags: php, сессия, unset

Сессионные переменные нужны на сайте только для одной страницы. Например, сайт онлайн-кинотеатра. На странице поиска фильмов я использую сессионную переменную `$_SESSION['search']` (точнее, это даже массив `[search]['category]` и `[search][item]` но это не важно). Без сессии невозможно реализовать сложный выбор фильмов по категориям с последующей пагинацией найденных записей.
Это все хорошо, но на остальных страницах сессионная переменная абсолютно не нужна, поэтому висит "мертвым грузом", перегружая ресурсы сервера.

Вопрос: как можно отследить, что сессия больше не нужна и совершить над ней unset? Или мне придется (допустим в index.php) отслеживать название страницы, и если это не страница поиска, то уничтожать `$_SESSION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как можно отследить, что сессия больше не нужна... ?

Если вы, разрабатывая этот сайт, не знаете ответа на этот вопрос, то откуда же мы его можем знать? Логику сайта продумывает разработчик.

> как можно... совершить над ней unset?

```
unset($_SESSION['search']);
```

> Или мне придется (допустим в index.php) отслеживать название страницы,
>   и если это не страница поиска, то уничтожать $_SESSION?

Если скрипт должен работать только на определённой странице, то почему бы и нет? `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` в руки и дерзайте!

Comment: ну вот и весь ответ! А кто там такой чересчур умный - заминусовал меня? У меня работает Роутер, разбивает REQUEST_URI на компоненты, передает их соответствующему Контроллеру, наверное я прикажу Роутеру, если увидит, что страница не "search" и isset(сессия) - втопку! Сессия-то одна, но если будет over 9000 000 зрителей, будет накладно для хостинга... Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Deus ещё полезные функции [`session_destroy()`](http://www.php.su/functions/?session-destroy) и [`session_unset()`](http://www.php.su/functions/?session-unset). Тоже можно применить в вашем случае для освобождения ресурсов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так наверняка уничтожить можно

```
unset($_SESSION['search']);
session_destroy();
```